# Merge C source files as CIL

Tags: frama-c

I would like to merge C source files as I was doing with [CIL](https://github.com/cil-project/cil) and the cilly script. Does Frama-c provide this scripting functionality ?

Answer (score 2):

Frama-C will link together all the files that are given on its command line, i.e. if you do

```
frama-c file1.c file2.c -print
```

Frama-C will pretty-print the content of `file1.c` and `file2.c`, after having taken care that there's no incoherence between them (e.g. a function `f` declared with incompatible parameter types).